# I cannot insert the multiple values to the sql database php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, phpmyadmin

I cannot insert multiple values to the database but when I echo the array, it outputs. what is the problem? i think my code is correct but I doubt on the saving to the database part. [the output of my program, which outputs the array values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aceor.png)

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method = "post">
        Student ID <input type="text" name = "student_id"> <br>
        OR NO <input type = "text" name = "or_no"> <br>
        Requests
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Replacement_of_Registration"> Replacement_of_Registration <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Good Moral Certificate">Good Moral Certificate <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Honorable Dismissal ">Honorable Dismissal <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Transcript of Record">Transcript of Record <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Diploma">Diploma<br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "CUE Request"> CUE Request <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "CMI Request">CMI Request <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Entrance Exam">Entrance Exam <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "School fees-Medical/Dental Laboratory ">School fees-Medical/Dental Laboratory <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "School fees-Transcript/Honorable">School fees-Transcript/Honorable<br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "School fees-Library">School fees-Library <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "ac_description[]" value = "Affiliation Fees">Affiliation Fees <br>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Save"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]=="Save")
    {
        $student_id = $_POST["student_id"];
        $or_no = $_POST["or_no"];
        $ac_description = $_POST["ac_description"];
        print_r ($ac_description);
        $status1="processing";
        $qty=1;
        $col_credit = 80;
        $dep_credit = 80;
        $col_debit = 0;
        $dep_debit = 0;
        $db = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "turtledove", "accounting");
        if (!$db)
        {
            die ("ERROR!!!!!!>>>");
        }
        if ($ac_description)
        {
                foreach ($ac_description as $ac)
                { 
                mysqli_query($db, "insert into or_header (detail_no,or_ no, ac_description, student_id, date1, status1, qty, 
                col_credit, col_debit, dep_credit, dep_debit)
                values (".$or_no.", '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$ac)."',".$student_id.",curdate(),".$status1.",
                ".$qty.",".$col_credit.",".$col_debit.",".$dep_credit.",".$dep_debit.")");

                }


        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: i dont get any errors but i cannot insert to the database, i dont know where the problem is becaus as far as i know, my source code is correct.

Comment: Don't think you passing a value for `detail_no` in your insert (seems to start at `or_ no`.  Also you should learn to use prepared statements and bind variables, would be a lot safer.  Also just noticed that the `or_ no` has a space in the middle.

Comment: You sure there is no errors? `mysqli_error()` doesn't show anything?

Comment: the only error trap that i have is    if (!$db)
        {
            die ("ERROR!!!!!!>>>");
        }

Comment: Also I think you are missing `detail_no` in `values()` part of your query, and there are space in column name in insert statement (you have "or_ no" space after underscore)

Comment: foreach ($ac_description as $ac)
    { 
    mysqli_query($db, "insert into or_header (or_no, ac_description, student_id, date1, status1, qty, 
    col_credit, col_debit, dep_credit, dep_debit)
    values (".$or_no.", '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$ac)."',".$student_id.",curdate(),".$status1.",
    ".$qty.",".$col_credit.",".$col_debit.",".$dep_credit.",".$dep_debit.")");
    
    }

Comment: i've already fixed the space in or_no, but it still the same

Comment: Have you tried printing out the full SQL with all the substitutions and run it in something like phpmyadmin, it can easily show any errors in your SQL.

Comment: try this `if (!mysqli_query(... paste your query there...) { echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($db); }`